# GA sessions - Time Zone

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question regarding sessions attribution in Google Analytics.

Imagine I am in New York and it's 9.00pm on 01/01/2018 and I am visiting "www.amazon.fr" and it's therefore 3.00am on 02/01/2018 in France. Will my session belong to the "01/01/2018" data or to the "02/01/2018" data ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time reported in GA is relative to the timezone set in the view settings. In your case, assuming your view is set to France time, it will be of the next day 3am. 
[image]